# Default value for preceding parameters

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

This is some tricky question. How can i pass value to last parameter if preceding parameters has default value?

```js
function sum(a=10, b=7, c){
 return a+b+c;
}

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = sum(10);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

I want 10 to be assign to **c** and result as **sum** of 3 values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use named parameters (destructuring assignment). Basically your funcion receives an object, and you still can set the default values and pass only the properties you need. And with this approach the order of the properties doesnt matter at all. You can call `sum({ c: 2 })`  or `sum({ a: 3, c: 4})` .. or whatever.

Further reading: http://2ality.com/2011/11/keyword-parameters.html

```js
function sum({a=10, b=7, c}){
 return a+b+c;
}

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = sum({ c: 10 });
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Note regarding the other answers: IMHO passing falsy values like undefined or null to as arguments, makes a function very inconsistent and hard to test. Thats why I would use named params if I know that some fields might not be needed for x reasons.

Comment: Could you please explain?

Comment: @ketan Ive updated my answer and added some valuable info :)

Comment: @Ivar idk if there is an "official name" I know many names for it : 'named parameters', 'parameter context matching', 'destructuring assignment' .. etc But ty Ive updated my answer to avoid future confussions.

Answer (score 1):

Pass `undefined` explicitly to get the default values:

```js
function sum(a = 10, b = 7, c) {
  return a + b + c;
}

const result = sum(undefined, undefined, 10);

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I used default parameter then, why should i pass 3 values?

Comment: Because the default parameters are returned if the value passed to them is `undefined`. Usually the default parameters are the last parameters, and when you pass the 1st param, the other params are implicitly `undefined`. In this case, it's the last param, so you need to pass `undefined` explicitly. If you want unordered params with defaults, use object destructuring as suggested by @CristianS.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare as: `function sum(c, a=10, b=7)` then use: `sum(10)`!

```js
function sum(c, a=10, b=7){
 return a+b+c;
}

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = sum(10);
```

```html
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Why to change the order?

Comment: It is the only way to use follow your way (`sum(10)`)! And with the sum, ordinary of numbers isn't important!

Answer (score 0):

```js
function sum(a , b = 10, c=7) {
  return a + b + c;
}
```